# Bootstrap columns wrap if content too long

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not sure if wrap is the right word, but i have a column that can be very long.
And i would like it to wrap to the next set of columns when it reaches the end of the div.

what i would like:

```
col-3 col-3 a
a     a     a
a     a     a 
a     a     col-3
a     a     a
______________ end of div
```

I would like the second col-3 to wrap at the size of the first col-3, in the end to have 2 columns the same size and one with what's left over after the length is filled.

What i have right now:

```
col-3 col-3 col-3
a     a     a
a     a     
a     a     
a     a 
      a
      a
      a
      a    
______________ end of div
```

My code:

```html
<div className="container">
      <h2>{listing.name}</h2>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <SlickAll />
            <ul>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
        <div className="col-md-3 mh-100">
          <ul className="list-group">
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
             <li>asd </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-3 mh-100">
          <ul className="list-group">
             <li>asd </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a more accurate HTML only representation? Are you using `col-md-6` and `col-md-3` or 2 col-3's?

Comment: Hello, one col-md-6, one col-md-3 that i would like to wrap into another col-md-3 if necessary if the div length is filled.

Comment: @Zim i edited my question, hopefully its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox column wrap, and limit the height of the right side columns by placing them in a `position:absolute` container...

```
   <div class="row my-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                <li>list</li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100">
                <ul class="list-group d-flex flex-column flex-wrap mh-md-100">
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                    <li>list</li>
                    ...
                    <li>listend</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/L7WH4YZNBW

The only extra CSS is to make the max-height work responsively. This allows the columns to stack vertically on smaller screens (less than `md` width)...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mh-md-100 {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, the li elements that got wrapped on the second column do not respond to padding style, and so they are stuck to the first row. How can i style them to not touch?